# Downloaded items with Chrome always have incomplete icons

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Whenever I download something with Google Chrome, all icons on the desktop has the unfinished icon.

It does it with all files types.

Is there a way to fix this issue?!

[image]

Comment: What happens if you download in the Download folder instead to desktop?

Comment: This question is lacking some details which might help to find a solution for you: Are only icons of files downloaded via Chrome impacted or other icons as well? Once downloads are completed, can you work with the files as usual (open them etc.) despite the "wrong" icon? Does the icon change after a reboot? Does it happen for all users or only for one?

Answer (score 1):

I found if you Get Info (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>) the file then close the Get Info window without doing anything it will magically complete. Then to force an icon put the file into a new folder.